# Same gridview but different behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two gridview on a page and both grid-view are exactly same except their id. But the behavior of one grid-view is unexpected. when i have use EmptyDataTemplate then only one grid-view shows it, other does not. when i  use jquery data-table only one grid support other does not. i am unable to find out the reason behind this. Please help me.
 here i am providing you the code of grid-view binding and their markup.

this one is fine

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gridAttributes" CssClass="table " runat="server"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None">
      <EmptyDataTemplate>
               No Attribute Available.<a href="Ecommerce.aspx"> Click here to add attributes.</a>
      </EmptyDataTemplate>
      <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Include">
              <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:CheckBox ID="cbInclude" 
                            EcommrceAttributesID='<%# Eval("EcommrceAttributesID") %>'
                            runat="server" />
              </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
              <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("AttributeName")%></ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Values">
              <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Attributevalues")%></ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

this one is causing problem

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridAttributeSC" CssClass="table " runat="server"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No Attribute Available.<a href="Ecommerce.aspx"> Click here to add attributes.</a>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Include">
              <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="cbInclude" 
                           EcommrceAttributesID='<%# Eval("EcommrceAttributesID") %>'
                           runat="server" />
              </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
               <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("AttributeName")%></ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Values">
               <ItemTemplate><%# Eval("Attributevalues")%></ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and here is binding code

```
if (eCommerceSettingId != "0")
{
      clsEcommerceAttributes attr = new clsEcommerceAttributes();
      DataSet dsAttr = attr.getEcommerceAttributesByEcommerceSettingID(new Guid(eCommerceSettingId));
      gridAttributes.DataSource = dsAttr;
      gridAttributes.DataBind();

      gridAttributeSC.DataSource = dsAttr;
      gridAttributeSC.DataBind();

}
else
{
      gridAttributes.DataSource = null;
      gridAttributes.DataBind();
      gridAttributeSC.DataSource = null;
      gridAttributeSC.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Where do you use "binding code"? And also please Show us Page_Load and Pre_Render (If you use any) event codes.